# どの　and　どち when and how to use each?

Tags: grammar, words

Recently, I have been struggling with the correct usage of 「どの」and「どち」. Is it correct to think of them in the following way?
「どの」= what (I get this confused with「なん」and「なに」as well)
「どち」= which

When listing two options do I use「どの」or「どち」?
When listing three or more options do I use「どの」or「どち」?

Or am I thinking about this in the wrong way? Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct usage for どっち/どちら　is being answered well in here; [Can どっち mean which one of many?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14997/can-%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1-mean-which-one-of-many)

When it comes to 「どの」, the 「ど」in this case is actually a reading for the kanji 「何」which makes it 「何の」(*but it is always written in hiragana only*)

Therefore, it would give it the meaning of **what(kind)** or **what(way)**

example; あなたはどの肉が好きですか
(What kind of meat do you like?)

---

also if you take the 「どの位(くらい), it will have a meaning of **how long**, **how much**, **how far**.
example; この雪はどのくらい降るのだろうか (How much will it snow?)